# How to set where the ground in using physics in swift, and jumping only once with applyImpulse

Tags: ios, swift, game-physics

I am trying to make a jump and run game in Swift, and I have run into two main problems.

The first is that I applied the gravity to the GameScene, but every time I jump, the player goes through the floor instead of stopping at its original position. I tried setting dynamic = false before jumping, and then setting it to true after jumping, but it still falls through the floor.

Another problem that I have is that when clicked, the player applies and impulse every click and therefore jumps, double jumps, triple jumps, etc. I can't seem to figure out how to make it only jump when it is at the ground level.

Here is the code.

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    //basically my tap to start feature. i set the player's dynamic to false at the play screen, then on the first tap it runs the game, then every other tap it normally jumps
    if player.physicsBody!.dynamic {
        player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 5.0))
    } else {
    spawnBarrels()
    addTimer()
    runScore()
    startLabel.removeFromParent()
    player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 4.0))
    }
}
 func addGround(){
    //adds the ground 
    addChild(ground)
    ground.size = CGSize(width: size.width * 1, height: size.height * 0.1)
    ground.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.05)

    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: size.height, height: size.height * 0.1))

    ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
}

var canJump = true
//change

func didBeginContactGround(contact: SKPhysicsContact){
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    switch(contactMask){
    case PhysicsCategory.Player | PhysicsCategory.Ground:
        canJump = true
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the first part of your question:**
You have the collision, contact, and category bitmasks mixed up. These are their Definitions/Uses:

- **Category**: What type of object it is (`PhysicsCategory.Player`)
- **Collision**: What objects it collides with (`PhysicsCategory.Ground`)
- **Contact**: What the game should test collision for. You can then reference the colliding of two objects in:
  `func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact){}`

Right now you're telling your player to check for collision between it and other players, and collide with nothing (If this doesn't make sense I suggest looking into these bitmasks further). If you want your player to die when it comes into contact with an obstacle, you would set its Contact to be `PhysicsCategory.Obstacle`.

**For the Second Part:** You can set the contact bitmask to be `PhysicsCategory.Ground`, and if you also want obstacles, it can be: `PhysicsCategory.Ground | PhysicsCategory.Obstacle`. Then you can make a boolean called canJump, and only allow jumping when this is `true`.

Then you would write this somewhere in your code:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    switch(contactMask) {
    case PhysicsCategory.Player | PhysicsCategory.Ground:
        canJump = true;
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Then whenever your player jumps, set canJump to `false`. This will make it so that when the player hits the ground, they can then jump again. If you want to be more precise, instead of setting canJump to `false` after jumping, set it `false` after the player is no longer in contact with the ground by making another identical function but changing the name to `didEndContact`, and setting it to `false` instead of `true`.

Also, dynamic should always be `true` for the player. Here's a link that should help if you don't understand the different bitmasks:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/26/2/loading-a-level-categorybitmask-collisionbitmask-contacttestbitm

Comment: Make another SpriteKitNode just like the player. Mess around with the different settings to make it act like a stationary object (I.E setting dynamic to `false`, etc.) If you want it to not be visible, put it just barely offscreen by 1 pixel along the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I've been working at this for a while now, and I can't really seem to understand it. Is there any additional explanation that you can give me?

Comment: Sure thing - let me see what you have so I know what problems you're running into

Comment: I added the code into my question. Basically I set the gravity but i need the player to stop falling when he hits the ground. I also need the player to jump only when he is touching the ground.